# Select vertices on one side of a cube

Tags: python, mesh, 3d-view, vertices

The aim is to select the vertices of one side of a cube.

My intention was to change the view's orientation using bpy.ops.view3d.viewnumpad and then select the vertices that are visible, using bpy.ops.vew3d.select_border.

```
    def changeView(view):
               for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
                 if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                     override = bpy.context.copy()
                     override['area'] = area
                     bpy.ops.view3d.viewnumpad(override, type=view, align_active=False)
                  break   



    def select_border(mesh,context, view3dAreaAndRegion=None, extend=True):
          if not view3dAreaAndRegion:
            view3dAreaAndRegion = getView3dAreaAndRegion(context)
          view3dArea, view3dRegion = view3dAreaAndRegion

          override = context.copy()
          override['area'] = view3dArea
          override['region'] = view3dRegion

          #change orientation to Front side
          changeView('FRONT');

          bpy.ops.view3d.select_border(override,
                                       gesture_mode=3,
                                       xmin=0,
                                       xmax=view3dArea.width,
                                       ymin=0,
                                       ymax=view3dArea.height,
                                       extend=extend)
           return view3dAreaAndRegion
```

This works, so long as I click 'Run Script' twice, or if the View is already set manually by hitting 1 on the number pad.

However the problem is, if I pan around,then hit 'Run Script' once, it selects all the vertices that are visible from that angle, before changing the view's orientation to Front.

Comment: If using predefined options, you can try Select > Side Of Active and set up its options (Axis of selection, Positive/Negative etc) or Shift+G > Co-Planar (in face selection mode), it might be similar to your needs.

Comment: Comparing face normal to views' normal could be another way to do this without operators. [Also Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/40826/edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use some vector math to select the right facing verts (deselect all verts and run this in object mode in the text editor, or paste in the console)

```
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import Vector

for v in (v for v in C.object.data.vertices if v.normal.dot(Vector((1,0,0))) > 0):
    v.select = True
```

alternately, to select the left side, change the Vector to (-1,0,0). Top, (0,0,1) etc.